# interpreter of php. Read, translate and execute the intructions of the source code?

Tags: php, interpreter

I have a very basic question about the operation of the php interpreter.
The interpreters read instruction by instruction, translate and execute them, but if the following code is executed from the command line:

```
<? php
    echo "hello world";
    eco "incorrect line";
?>
```

The first instruction does not execute and the error of the third line is displayed.

Could you explain the reason?
thank you

Comment: Because of the error. Most languages first scan for errors and halt on them then display the result of the code

Comment: Reason of what?

Comment: PHP is _not_ an interpreter in the classic sense. It uses a just-in-time compiler to compile the source code to byte code, then that byte code is interpreted. A syntax error occurs at compilation time, so before execution, regardless of where the faulty line is located.

Comment: But if the code is compiled and you add a second wrong line, only shows the first wrong line

Comment: Yes, halt on error. It halts on first error it encounters always

Comment: "But if the code is compiled and you add a second wrong line, only shows the first wrong line " -- the entire file is compiled each time you run it or each time it changes, depending on the server setup.  So when you "add a second line" compilation starts over.  Then (unlike C++) it stops at the first error instead of looking for every error after that.

Comment: So if the code uses a just-in-time compiler, it isn`t an interpreter, it's a compiler